# How to group results based on same value in MySQL or node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a MySQL database with two tables: **albums** and **photos**. This is what the albums table looks like:

```
+---------+-------------+---------------------------+--------+
| albumID | albumName   | albumDescription          | userID |
+---------+-------------+---------------------------+--------+
| 1       | Winter 2018 | Pictures from winter time | 1      |
| 2       | Spring 2018 | Pictures from spring time | 1      |
| 3       | Summer 2018 | Pictures from summer time | 1      |
| 4       | Fall 2018   | Pictures from fall time   | 1      |
+---------+-------------+---------------------------+--------+
```

The photos table looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+
| photoID | albumID | photoCategory | photoURL   |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+
| 1       | 1       | dog           | photo1.jpg |
| 2       | 1       | cat           | photo2.jpg |
| 3       | 1       | dog           | photo3.jpg |
| 4       | 4       | dog           | photo4.jpg |
+---------+---------+---------------+------------+
```

I now return the photos associated with the albumID: `SELECT * FROM photos WHERE albumID = 1`. This returns the information of all three photos like this when retrieving the data in node.js:

```
[{"photoID":1,"albumID":1,"photoCategory":"dog","photoURL":"photo1.jpg"},
{"photoID":2,"albumID":1,"photoCategory":"cat","photoURL":"photo2.jpg"},
{"photoID":3,"albumID":1,"photoCategory":"dog","photoURL":"photo3.jpg"}]
```

However, I am looking for a way to group the results together based on the category. What I would like to achieve is the following:

```
["photoCategory":"dog" = [
    {"photoID":1,"albumID":"1","photoURL":"photo1.jpg"},
    {"photoID":3,"albumID":"1","photoURL":"photo3.jpg"}],
 "photoCategory":"cat" = [
    {"photoID":2,"albumID":"1","photoURL":"photo2.jpg"}]]
```

I wonder if this is possible to achieve with MySQL?
If not, can I filter my results in node.js to accomplish the same outcome?

Comment: SQL does NOT return JSON formatted results by itself. You are calling the SQL query through some code, it is that code that produces the current JSON result.

Comment: I figured - so I would need to implement a way to parse it into the right format in node.js, right?

Comment: Seems so - but know almost nothing about Node.js I'm afraid

Comment: Your desired result isn't a valid JavaScript object. Objects are `{key: value, key: value, ...}`. Arrays are `[value, value, value, ...]`. What is `["photoCategory":"dog" = [...]]` supposed to be? It's not an array, it's not an object.